# Magento 2 | Is there an observable event for when the checkout begins?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

when the checkout is started I need to modify the quote.

Is there an event when the checkout is started?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` observer

create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index">
       <observer name="vendor_module_observer_checkoutinit" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkoutinit" />
   </event>
</config>
```

and create observer in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Checkoutinit.php`

```
class Checkoutinit implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
     //$order= $observer->getData('order');
     //$order->doSomething();

     return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: for me controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index does not work, only controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index works

Answer (score 2):

To do some logic before placing the order, you can use the event

`sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

available in `/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement` before placing the order.

Or in worst case, you can also override the `/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/SaveOrder` Controller, do your stuff before the line `$this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();` which is responsible for saving the order.